# Git with Dropbox shared folder

Tags: git, github, cloud, dropbox

Me and a coworker have a shared Dropbox folder with code, output files, etc. We both edit files there, and the local code runs with file paths specific (relative) to the folder. And other users (project participants) also have access to it.

Now, we want to use Git for version control. So we initialize a repository at Github. However, since the local folder is shared, any changes I make to it -- before committing and pushing -- will be synced over Dropbox to her local folder. This causes a host of conflicts and defeats the purpose of Git altogether. Besides, the other project participants don't use Git and, thus, require a Dropbox-ready folder with the current structure of the project.

**Question**: is there a workflow to make this work? We need to both have a local-origin Git framework but still keeping a synced Dropbox folder with the current repository state.

I've unsuccessfully tried `git-remote-dropbox`, this [answer](https://discuss.ropensci.org/t/peace-between-git-and-dropbox-with-git-worktree/289), and others.

Comment: Just exclude dropbox from your workflow, thats it. You work on your PC, your coworker works on her. Whenever next portion of changes is ready, it's delivered to GitHub. Non-contributors don't need to know git, they should be fine with simply downloading the latest version as zip archive from GitHub via big green button, doesn't require a lot of skills.

Answer (score -1):

First of all: `git-remote-dropbox` is no valid git command. I don't know where you think you found this but it doesn't exist.

Furthermore I really understand can't your use case: Why do you need the dropbox? If I got you right you want to use 2 separate git repos to do "versioning" and do syncing via dropbox? Why isn't it possible to just host a repo on GitHub (or similar) and drop the dropbox?

One of the main purposes of git is to work efficiently together and avoid/ solve problems when syncing with different versions and edits. To sync it via another provider like dropbox is probably somehow possible but it is inefficient and causes errors like you encountered.

Please rethink your infrastructure. If you really just use dropbox to sync via the internet then I highly recommend you to visit [GitHub](https://github.com/) to store and manage code for free (there are free alternatives aswell).

> BTW: I don't know how experienced you are with git but there is the branching system which can be used for holding a current state of the repository while also working on different branches. More for that [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). Here is another [good guide](https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.html).

**EDIT**: Like you pointed out `git-remote-dropbox` is a external tool. I just took a brief look at the readme section of the github project and found the following:

> Q: Why shouldn't I keep my Git repository in Dropbox and let the client sync it?
>
> A: There seem to be a lot of articles on the Internet recommending this
> as a good workflow. However, *this is not a good idea*! The desktop
> client is not aware of how Git manages it's on-disk format, so if
> there are concurrent changes or delays in syncing, it's possible to
> have conflicts that result in a corrupted Git repository.

Comment: Thanks. First, git-remote-dropbox is a tool outside Git: https://github.com/anishathalye/git-remote-dropbox. Second, the other users in our project don't use Github, so they simply want a Dropbox-ready version of the folder to run code.

Comment: After I posted my answer I thought of something like that external tool. Thank you for explaining your context. My idea would be: Build a simple script on a server copying the latest state of your repositories main branch into a dropbox folder. I believe you can do this with a simple `batch` file using the `cp` command on linux and the `xcopy` on windows. This script you can either run every few seconds checking if there was a change in the repo or you can use a [webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) to trigger the script. I hope this helps you.